# getText property of TextSnapShot is returning empty text

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

I am having a movie clip and i am getting TextSnapShot from that. I am able to perform all the functions like getTextPosition which returns the position of any given word in the clip and i am getting correct values. But whenever i am calling getText property its returning empty text, whereas it should return the text between given starting position and end position.

Now when i am adding that clip to a container suppose VBox, and then i call the function getText its returning me the text. I am able to do this but still i don't know why its behaving like that and i would like to know that. So if anybody can explain me the cause of this behavior the help would be highly appreciated from me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If any body faces this problem ever i have got the solution. You will be only able to get textSnapShot from a clip only if the clip is added to some container. If its not added to any container you will get empty textSnapShot

Happy Coding :)